# Search Input with Semantic UI React OnChange Very Slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm doing a simple filter on my data using the Semantic UI React 'Input' Component.  The data loads first, and then i apply the search filter to narrow down the data based on the user input.

It works, but when typing, it's very slow.  I saw another user with a similar issue and someone mentioned onBlur but that doesn't seem to be working for me.   Here is my Search component, which is passing a search state back to one of my other components which updates the data.  Anyone have any recommendations here?

```
 import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { searchChange, clearSearch } from "../reducers/searchReducer";

const Search = props => {
  const handleSearch = event => {
    props.searchChange(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  const style = {
    marginBottom: 10
  };

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <Input
        icon="search"
        placeholder="Enter filter..."
        onChange={handleSearch}
      />

    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    search: state.search,
    filter: state.filter
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  searchChange,
  //   filterChange,
  clearSearch
})(Search);
```